# Develop JavaScript API to expose services

Tags: javascript, web-services, api

We are planning to develop a JavaScript API to expose some of our Java EE based services. We are doing this keeping Google Maps API
in mind. Can someone please suggested where we should start and the approaches that we need to follow to create a useful and
extensible JavaScript API? Any suggestion will be greatly helpful for us.

Comment: I'm afraid this isn't really the right kind of Q&A question for stackoverflow.  Might be better on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/.  See the stackoverflow [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: I'm so sorry for this.Is it possible for me to move this question with comments and answers to the other site?

Answer (score 1):

More than google maps, I think you should look at twitter which has a very nice REST API. (https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api) REST is the key of building your API.

Part from that, you should also think about generating API keys, so you have control about who is doing what with your services

Also that seems like a good reading to start:

http://blog.steveklabnik.com/posts/2011-07-03-nobody-understands-rest-or-http

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Will surely look at this.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely look to make it a RESTful JSON Api and then you'll be able to use it for various purposes. APIs like twitter et. al. are good models (although there is a lot of back and forth about what is completely REST).

I'm a big fan of Mike Pearce's take on how to design good APIs: http://blog.mikepearce.net/2010/08/08/api-anti-patterns-how-not-to-write-a-restful-api/